# What renders the gallery images? Gallery returns thumbnail versions

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, extensions, thumbnail, gallery-image

I'm currently making a M2 site and I'm fairly new to the platform. I'm trying to make it so that people can customize their product. I found this extension: https://github.com/develodesign/magento2-productdesignr

It works perfectly! However, the gallery images turn into thumbnail size for some reason when I enable it. I'm wondering, what magento 2 function controls how the images are shown in the gallery? Maybe I can start debugging if I knew where to look. I've attached 2 pictures, one that currently shows the thumbnail size when the extension is enabled and the 2nd one shows the normal use case.

[image]

[image]